# DCOS CLI install not working

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

Running DCOS 1.8 on Centos.
I installed the CLI as below:
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/cli/install/

When I try to do a spark install I get the below error. Any ideas?

```
./dcos package install spark
ip-172-16-6-6.localdomain's username: admin
admin@ip-172-16-6-6.localdomain's password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "cli/dcoscli/subcommand.py", line 99, in run_and_capture
 File "cli/dcoscli/package/main.py", line 21, in main
 File "cli/dcoscli/util.py", line 21, in wrapper
 File "cli/dcoscli/package/main.py", line 35, in _main
 File "dcos/cmds.py", line 43, in execute
 File "cli/dcoscli/package/main.py", line 356, in _install
 File "dcos/cosmospackage.py", line 191, in get_package_version
 File "dcos/cosmospackage.py", line 366, in __init__
 File "cli/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 826, in       json
 File "json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
 File "json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
 File "json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
 ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: I'm a developer for the DC/OS CLI. can you paste the output of `./dcos --log-level=debug package install spark` and `./dcos --version`? Thanks!

Comment: MainThread: 2016-10-10 23:33:13,369 dcos/cosmospackage.py:enabled:73 - Error while fetching [https://ip-172-16-6-6.localdomain/capabilities]: HTTP 502: Bad Gateway

Comment: Also when I go to the DCOS 1.8 web GUI, Universe -> Packages -> I get an error has occurred. and when I click on installed it says "Cannot connect with Server"

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue to.  For me it was because I forgot to install virtualenv.  `pip install virtualenv`.